# Clase genérica para respuestas Json C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos tengo la siguiente situación, estoy consumiendo un servicio **REST** en donde todas las respuestas que me manda el servidor tienen el mismo formato, entonces necesito recibir y transformar las respuesta del servidor en mi app **Xamarin**, Se me ocurren dos soluciones, de las cuales ya intenté una pero no me salió muy bien .

- Crear una carpeta por vista donde pueda escribir una clase por petición, el problema que tuve con esto es que no pude hacerles referencia de manera propicia Es decir no pude hacer esto

> using Miproyecto.Models.Orden;

Ni tampoco esto

> using Miproyecto.Orden;

- Otra cosa que quisiera saber si es posible es crear alguna clase generica , a la que quizá le mande un objeto que describa mi petición o algo similar para este tipo de respuestas.

La clase que cree se llama **Table1**

```js
{
  "DatosEnvio": {},
  "DatosEnvioJson": {},
  "tablas": {
    "Table1": [

      {
        "IdUsuario": 1,
        "Longitud": "5.23232",
        "Latitud": "-5.32323",
        "FechaAlta": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Estatus": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "bandera": "0",
  "mensaje": "SE OBTUVIERON LOS DATOS DE MANERA CORRECTA"
}
```

```js
{
  "DatosEnvio": {},
  "DatosEnvioJson": {},
  "tablas": {
    "Table1": [{
        "destino": "67",
        "inicio": "2018-03-14T00:00:00",
        "termino": "2018-03-14T00:00:00",
        "dias": 67,
        "cuota": 67,
        "importes": 67,
        "idOrden": 1
      },
      {
        "destino": "67",
        "inicio": "2018-03-28T00:00:00",
        "termino": "2018-03-30T00:00:00",
        "dias": 67,
        "cuota": 67,
        "importes": 67,
        "idOrden": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "bandera": "0",
  "mensaje": "Opc 5"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si copias un codigo json y lo pegas en visual studio usando Edit->Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Clases te crea el toda la estructura de clases que necesitas, por ejemplo para el primer texto que pones se queda asi

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Datosenvio DatosEnvio { get; set; }
    public Datosenviojson DatosEnvioJson { get; set; }
    public Tablas tablas { get; set; }
    public string bandera { get; set; }
    public string mensaje { get; set; }
}

public class Datosenvio
{
}

public class Datosenviojson
{
}

public class Tablas
{
    public Table1[] Table1 { get; set; }
}

public class Table1
{
    public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Longitud { get; set; }
    public string Latitud { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }
    public object Estatus { get; set; }
}
```

Una vez tienes esa estructura de clases tienes que coger el texto Json y deserializarlo a esos objetos, yo te recomiendo que uses la libreria de nuget Newtonsoft.Json

Una vez la instales, suponiendo que guardas el json en un string llamada textoJson la conversion es asi de facil

```
Rootobject objeto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(textoJson);
```

Y de esa manera ya has transformado un json en un objeto usable en tu codigo.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, hago la mayoría de lo que me aconsejas, pero si te fijas tengo 2 respuestas con la misma estructura pero diferente contenido en table1 , y eso es lo que necesito resolver , no la conversión en si

Comment: En principio es un fallo de diseño que el servidor te mande dos clases que se llaman Table1 y tienen contenido diferente. Asi de pronto la unica forma que se me ocurre es que hagas un objeto Table1 que tenga los campos de las dos opciones.